# Closing WordDBAdapter in onDestroy

Tags: android, sqlite, ondestroy

I need to close my WordDBAdapter object in the onDestroy method in Android. Is one of these better than the other?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if(dbWord instanceof WordDBAdapter)
    {
        dbWord.close();
    }
}
```

----- OR ------

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if(dbWord != null)
    {
        dbWord.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in your code, whatever approach you use the ordering of statement should be as follow:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if(dbWord != null)
    {
        dbWord.close();
    }
 super.onDestroy();
}
```